# How to keep Gazebo open and load new changes to it from URDF file?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, roslaunch, urdf

I have a launch file for gazebo that works fine in terms of loading the robot into the world. But the problem I have is that I have to keep ending Gazebo in terminal by using CTRL + C and then wait for it to stop fully and then relaunch it with the new changes. Is there a more efficient way to load new changes to Gazebo? I have tried searching online but I couldn't find anything that I understood. My launch file is included below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

<param name="robot_description" command="xacro '$(find my_robot)/urdf/my_1st_robot.urdf.xacro'"/>

<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher"/>
<node pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui" name="joint_state_publisher_gui"/>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="paused" value="false" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <arg name="gui" value="true" />
    <arg name="headless" value="false" />
    <arg name="debug" value="false" />
</include>

<node name="spawning_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model my_1st_robot -param robot_description"/>
</launch>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called xacro live, which may do what you want: https://github.com/orise-robotics/xacro_live
But I haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: Thanks for sending that, but its for ROS2. I am using ROS1 Melodic.